# How to read and process large csv objects from S3 using Python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I'm downloading csv files and processing the content by using Python 3.8.

I faced a memory error when downloading a large file, so, I need to download a certain amount of rows (let's say 10k rows), process and then read the next 10k rows until the entire csv is processed. So far, I read the entire csv and I decode it by converting it into a dictionary that preserves the headers and the values of each row:

```
    data = s3.get_object(Bucket=config.BUCKET_NAME, Key=source_file)
    contents = data['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(contents.splitlines(True))
```

I've been reading documentation and [download_fileobj](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj) can read an object in chunks and uses a callback method to process it, but the object is divided in bytes, and I need to divide it in rows to not split a row in the middle.

I prefer to not download the entire file into disk because I don't have a lot of space and that will require to delete the file after processing, so I prefer some way to do it directly in RAM, by using a library, method etc.

Ideas?

Comment: s3 doesn't understand rows. You will need to handle bytes in your code & re-process any rows split in the middle if you want to do multipart download. If you know how big each of your rows are (in bytes) this would be easier.

Comment: No, row size is variable. Yeah, with a fixed row size, I could use the download_fileobj method directly.

Comment: What about this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46435402?

Comment: You might want to investigate using [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/), which is a "drop-in replacement for Python’s built-in `open()` command". It takes care of all the hard stuff. So, just `import` the library, open the fil eand then read it with `DictReader()` as normal. See how you go! It can even read zip files without unzipping.